# remove ONE duplicate html tag only

Tags: c#, html

I already searched a long time but I didnt find an answer. I hope you can help me. So I want to remove one duplicate HTML tag for example:

I have a text like this: `<BIG><BIG><BIG>Text</BIG></BIG></BIG>`

and if I press a button it should be something like this: `<BIG><BIG>Text</BIG></BIG>`

I already tried `RegEx`but it will delete all HTML Tags. I also found the `HTML Agility Pack` but I dont know how to do it.

The `RegEx` I tried:

```
public static string RemoveHTML(string source)
{
return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your regex ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to do it with `HtmlAgility` pack. [**Full example in dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D7hwHZ)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<BIG><BIG><BIG>Text</BIG></BIG></BIG>");

var result = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("BIG").FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null)
{
    doc.DocumentNode.RemoveChild(result, true);
}
```

This should be enough. You are finding the first element big and remove it from the document without removing his children(this is done by true parameter in `RemoveChild`)

Comment: @nicoh ask one question per post this is policy with SO. You can ask more detail question and what exactly is the problem now with already my solution. I don't know what you to do in this case and what code return this. Probably you don't have any childs and you are trying to remove it.